# How to shortcut select Move tool without instantly being Move?

Tags: transforms, select

Shortcut G instantly makes mouse movements Move the selection.

Is there a way to activate the Move tool without it instantly going into this button-less move state?

Similarly for Rotation and Scale.

Comment: Well, so how do you want it to start? By pressing some other button to start it? So instead of pressing one button you want to press two? Then press `G` once just in your mind and press it actually when you would want to press the second button.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: love that comment!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>G</kbd>  activates grab/move/translate operator. Operator only works with this operation that starts when the operator is called. If you want to use a tool with a move gizmo, you have to select the tool from the Toolbar:

[image]

The hotkey combination to activate the tool is  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Space</kbd>   ->   <kbd>G</kbd> .  <kbd>Shift</kbd>   +   <kbd>Space</kbd>  calls the menu with all the tools and  <kbd>G</kbd>  selects the move tool from it.

[image]

If you are coming from another software and are more used to gizmos, I would like to encourage you to explore the way Blender works with the operators as well. You can off course use gizmos if you like and there are good use cases for them like for example they are probably more convenient for animating stuff, but the operators are very powerful and convenient once you get used to the way they work. You get [Numeric Input functionality](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/numeric_input.html) with them as well.

Comment: Another possibility would be, if most of the time you are moving (or rotating or scaling) objects, you could activate the _Object Gizmo_ > _Move_ (or _Rotate_ or _Scale_) from the _Show Gizmo_ menu, so that you do not have to switch to the tool for the action you are using the most and can just start by dragging the gizmo.

Comment: Thanks. I've already gotten used to the operators, and been trying to come to terms with how Blender works, and to grok it and get its feel/vibe/way. But wanted/needed, sometimes, a fast way to just get the Move/Rotate/Scale tools without them being in their immediate operational state.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann argh, this is fantastic. I can set all three to on, and it's a supergizmo all the time. Is there a shortcut to increase/decrease the size of the gizmo?

Comment: @Confused You can set it in the _Preferences_ > _Viewport_ > _Display_, there is a pixel value for _Gizmo Size_. But it's for all of them together, you cannot set the size separately for the individual gizmos. Oh, and you can switch the _Show Gizmo_ instead of _Default_ (which shows the orientation that the viewport is set to) for example to _Local_, so that the gizmos would always use the local orientation, no matter what the viewport is set to.